# Why is this Code broke the rules of Doctrine Symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

AssetId is always the same on the apple item

```
$items = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'banana'];
$itemRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Item::class);
$itemList = [];
foreach($items as $item) {
    $assetId = random_int(100,10000);
    // get items metadata, assetid is always null
    $item = $itemRepository->findOneBy(['name' => $item]);

    $item->setAssetId($assetId);
    // save the item object in an array for usage later but before, set now the nulled value
    $itemList[] = $item;
}

dd($itemList);
```

What is here wrong, because the assetid is not the right assetid, all apples have the same assetids

Comment: Did you try using a different variable name inside the `foreach`? Currently you are overwriting `$item` from the loop with the entity. It could mess things up.

Answer (score -1):

You can provide an autogenerated id to your Items with doctrine, not so sure what you're trying to do here.

In your item class:

```
#[ORM\Id]
#[ORM\GeneratedValue]
#[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
protected int $id;
```

And be sure to persist your items before you're trying to access them with the repository.

Comment: I know that, but my question is, why is the assetid instead of reseting the value for all items with the same name the same?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I missread your question. I understand what your problem is (I think).

You're trying to find one by the name in your foreach loop. This will always gather the FIRST item it encounters in your table. So, what your code is doing here, is always getting the same item and putting it in your $itemList array. You can see it in your dd, $itemList[0] and $itemList[5] have the same item id.

Comment: Thats right 0 and 5 have the same id, altought they should have another ids because i set in foreach the id.

Comment: Why don't you set them when creating your Items then?